# $\Delta \subset \Phi$ is a base in a root system imples $\Delta^\vee \subset \Phi^\vee$ is a base in a root system

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

(the notation here is compatible with J.E. Humphrey's *"Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory"*)

Let $\Phi \subset E$ be a root system.
Let $\Delta \subset \Phi$ be a base.
I already know that $\Phi^\vee \subset E$ is a root system.
I'd like to show that $\Delta^\vee \subset \Phi^\vee$ is a base.
(the notation $\alpha^\vee$ means $\frac{2\alpha}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$)

I tried 2 approaches and was stuck with about the same problem.

**Here's one attempt:**
I'll denote $\Delta=\Delta(\gamma)$ for some regular $\gamma \in E$.
I'd like to show that $\Delta(\gamma)^\vee=\Delta(\gamma^\vee)$.
I can easily show that $\Phi^+(\gamma)^\vee=(\Phi^\vee)^+(\gamma^\vee)$.
But then, how do I show that the indecomposable elements in $(\Phi^\vee)^+(\gamma^\vee)$ are exactly the duals of the indecomposable elements in $\Phi^+(\gamma)$?
(If this is true, than it goes the other way around too, so I'll try to show that the dual of a decomposable element is decomposable).
Denote $\alpha=\beta_1+\beta_2$ for some $\alpha,\beta_1,\beta_2 \in \Phi^+(\gamma)$. I'd like to show that $\alpha^\vee$ is decomposable too (in $(\Phi^+(\gamma))^\vee$). It is not true that $\alpha^\vee=\beta_1^\vee+\beta_2^\vee$ as I've seen by checking 2-dimensional examples. That's where I'm stuck.

(the other attempt was to go straight from the definition of a base, and there I had a problem with proving the integrality of the coefficients)

Another idea was to use the correspondence between Weyl chambers and bases. Both $\Phi$ and $\Phi^\vee$ define the same Weyl chambers. This gives a correspondence between the bases of $\Phi$ and the bases of $\Phi^\vee$. The correspondence is probably given by taking the dual of a base, but that's what I'm stuck at showing.

Comment: My question is a duplicate of this, but it has been answered. So perhaps this should be merged or closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @spin How can this be a duplicate? It was asked almost *two years before your own question*. Your question is the duplicate!

Comment: @spin You're kidding me, right?!

Comment: @FlybyNight: You don't understand my point, or maybe you didn't read my other comment. Yes, exactly like I said, my question is a duplicate. But this question has no answers, while my question already has two answers that solve the problem. Which is why this should be closed as a duplicate or merged..

Comment: @FlybyNight [According to the network meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/249378), age is just about the least important factor for determining the direction of duplication.

Comment: @epimorphic So because 28 people agree, it should be? If you say so.

Comment: @FlybyNight There's no need for you to get as dismissive as you have been in this thread.

There are numerous additional meta-questions that were marked as duplicates of the one I linked to, in the sidebar of that page. Feel free to check them out.